# How to get locale with region?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the current device locale with the region like "en_us","en_gb".

I am calling `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` and it returns only the two letters code `en`.

Comment: what you are try to achieve and whats your problem ?

Comment: @andruboy "only the two letters code"

Comment: yes that you have updated your question that i can see but what you want ? describe you problem

Comment: that when i change the device language to en(us) or en(gb) i will get the four digits locale and not only the two digits en

Comment: Locale.getDefault().getCountry()

Comment: @s1m3n thanks, both that and the language will do.

Comment: It looks like Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag() does just this. But only since Lollipop...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Format like "en_us" or "en_gb" has "language code"_"country code"

A Locale object contains both country code and language code.

So you can use below snippet to format your own code..

```
String cCode = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
String lCode = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
String code = lCode+"_"+cCode;
```

or

you can use `toString()` method on Locale object to get the data

```
String code = Locale.getDefault().toString();
```

Comment: 'String cCode = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();' returns blank in emulator. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Because you assigned no country. that happens when you set locale with language.

Answer (score 2):

The default `Locale` is constructed statically at runtime for your application process from the system property settings, so it will represent the `Locale` selected on that device **when the application was launched**.  Typically, this is fine, but it does mean that if the user changes their `Locale` in settings after your application process is running, the value of `getDefaultLocale()` probably will not be immediately updated.

If you need to trap events like this for some reason in your application, you might instead try obtaining the `Locale` available from the resource `Configuration` object, i.e.

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

You may find that this value is updated more quickly after a settings change if that is necessary for your application.

i have tested this :)

i have got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389349/android-get-current-locale-not-default/14389640#14389640) as link may be deleted so Answer copied :)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth pointing out that locale codes and language tags are related but different. Locale codes have an underscore separator (e.g. `fr_CA`), and language tags have a dash separator (e.g. `fr-ca`). I'm sure there are some deeper differences but that's beyond my pay grade.

This answer gives the result of various methods on the `Locale` class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23168383

It looks like you want the `toString()` method (to get the locale code) or the `toLanguageTag()` (to get the language tag).

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
Locale.getDisplayName();
```

This is shorthand for

```
Locale.getDisplayName(Locale.getDefault());
```

The documentation is in here:http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html