# Get proper language format in android

Tags: android, locale, multiple-languages

I have a multi language app which calls to api to get information depending of language code. For now I recognizning which Language is set by called `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();` and it gives me 2 characters language format ( for example `en,de,fr`) . I want to change it to `en-US, en-GB` and so on. Also i found incompatibilities - The Ukrainian language should be describe like uk but it is ua.
 I tried  `Locale.getDefault().toString();` and  `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()+"_"+ Locale.getDefault().getCountry();`  but it still gives me `en` and `en_` results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get locale with region?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484420/how-to-get-locale-with-region)

Comment: @Drivers The accept answer in that thread didnt works, what I write in question.