# Locale.getDefault() is outdated on some Android devices

Tags: android, locale

I have a broadcast receiver in my app that gets called when the device's locale changes.  There is a bug in my app on a few devices, specifically the Nexus 5x and Galaxy S8+ (and very likely others) where Locale.getDefault() returns the stale/previous value.  The localized strings are displaying correctly for the new language, but inside the application, our locale is outdated.  Any ideas?

ex:

`1) Device is in English -> App locale tells us we are in English.`

`2) Background the app and change the device language to German`

`3) App receives the locale changed broadcast event, Locale.getDefault() returns English instead of German`

I see German being returned here for many devices, but not all devices.

Answer (score 3):

As referenced in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389640), the default locale is defined statically [at the time the application is created](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault()). Try retrieving the locale from your Resources directly.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
    return getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
} else{
    return getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, each of these methods returns the same stale value.

Comment: facing same problem with android 11 any idea ?