# How to get device Locale on android pre Nougat (< api 24)?

Tags: android

I need to get the device `Locale` on android studio, but apparently the code below only works on api level 24+; How can i achieve the same result as this line of code in lower level apis?

```
getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android get current Locale, not default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389349/android-get-current-locale-not-default)

Answer (score 0):

well according to google docs the command `public Locale locale` has deprecated in API 24 and you are allowed to use `getLocales()` and `setLocales(android.os.LocaleList)` in API levels above 24. so you should yo`configuration.locale` instead in lower APIs.

```
@Override
 public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
    // update overrideConfiguration with your locale  
    setLocale(overrideConfiguration) // you need to implement this
}
super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration);
}
```

also check this out, it says it all:

[Set Locale programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985805/set-locale-programmatically)

Comment: If i use Locale loc = Locale.getDefault(); i can get the same result. Should i use it?

Comment: Locale.getDefault() has been added since API 24.

Answer (score 0):

For lower lavel api, you can use

```
Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389640/12676247