# How to identify device language from the App language in Android 13?

Tags: android, android-13, android-locale

I added support per app language to my app, the android 13 feature, now it is both English and Russian. I can change the app language from settings and no need to change the device language. Now for analytics purposes, I need to know the app language and the device language. But if my device is in English and the app is in Russian, I always receive Russian  -

```
   Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales.get(0).language  - ru

   context.resources.configuration.locales[0].language - ru

   Locale.getDefault().language - ru
```

I expect to receive **en** from

```
Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales.get(0).language
```

and
**ru** from

```
context.resources.configuration.locales[0].language
```

I will be glad for any help

Comment: Try this ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration())

Comment: The suggestion above does not work.  The first locale in the list is still the app language, not the device language.

Comment: @VivekGupta also receive the app language and not the device language

Answer (score 5):

I've been working with these:

```
AppCompatDelegate.getApplicationLocales()  // app locales
LocaleManagerCompat.getSystemLocales(Context) // system locales
```

`getApplicationLocales()` may return an empty array `[]` if there is no app-level setting. In that case, the system locale is being used.

I also use `AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat)` for consistency.

I'm not sure if there are non-Compat classes available for targeting *only* API 33, but this is currently working for me down to API 27.

As mentioned in another answer, you'll need to import `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-beta01` - see first line [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#androidx-impl).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that `AppCompatDelegate.getApplicationLocales()` only works after `onCreate()`

Answer (score 3):

The system locale list is available from [`LocaleManagerCompat.getSystemLocales(Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/LocaleManagerCompat#getSystemLocales(android.content.Context)) in `androidx.core:core:1.9.0-beta01` or later.