# In Per-app language, how to get App locale in API < 33 if System locale is different?

Tags: android, localization, locale, android-13

Android just introduced [Per-app language preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages) in Android API level 33 which let you change the app language regardless of the system language.

To [support devices that running API <= 32](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#android12-impl), Android in *Androidx Appcompat:* `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-beta01` has added:  `AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale);`

Now app language can be differ from system language.

Now there are 2 scenarios:

1. **In API <= 32:**
   `Locale.getDefault()` will return the system Locale which is equal to the app.
2. **In In API 33:**
    `Locale.getDefault()` will return the app locale not the system. And to get system locale, `LocaleManagerCompat.getSystemLocales(this).get(0)` can be used.

**My question:** How to get App locale in Android API <= 32 When using backward compatibility with out the need to use `Context`?

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73399280/how-to-identify-device-language-from-the-app-language-in-android-13) which is the opposite to what I need.

What I have tried to store Locale then fetch it whenever needed but this method needs `Context` which is incompetent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you use `AppCompatDelegate.getApplicationLocales()`?

I'm working through the same challenges as you right now, and this seems to work for me.

```
AppCompatDelegate -> [es_US] // after setting with AppCompatDelegate
Locale -> en_US // never changed, my system default

// Worked on emulators for both API 27 and 33
```

Comment: Thank you. `AppCompatDelegate.getApplicationLocales()` is returning a list, maybe you are using only 1 locale. So `AppCompatDelegate.getApplicationLocales().get(0)` is the way to get the the App locale.

Comment: It was returning empty to me because I was using it from BaseApplication. The docs state `Note: This API should always be called after Activity.onCreate().`