# How do I format date/time using Android device locale?

Tags: java, android, java-time

I am using the `java.time` package in Android, and I want to format a `ZonedDateTime` according to the user's device settings. I tried my default `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime/ofLocalizedTime`, but these always use a fixed format regardless of the device's setting (e.g., always using 12-hour format even if the handset is set to 24-hour).

How do I get a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` that respects the user's device preferences?

There are lots of questions on SO about formatting localized dates on Android, but all of the answers either refer to the legacy `Date` API or disregard the device's settings.

Comment: Reference, _[StackOverflow – Android get current Locale, not default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389640/17758716)_.

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` does not honor the user’s own localization-detail settings such as 12/24-hour clock.

### *CLDR*

Instead, that class draws upon a specific set of localization rules.

In older Java, a limited set of localization rules was bundled. In contrast, modern Java bundles the elaborately detailed localization rules published by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium), [*Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository). At first the CLDR was of secondary use in Java. In Java9+, the CLDR is the [default source of localization](https://openjdk.org/jeps/252) rules.

I do not know what Android uses as its source of localization rules.

#### Affecting output

I can understand wanting to alter localized output. For example, many of the localized formats use a two-digit year which I have found causes all kinds of confusion in business. I would like to override that one aspect of  localized formatters, to always use four-digit years.

One way to affect the localized output would be specifying a sub-culture. The CLDR defines many of these.

Perhaps you could start with a `DateTimeFormatter` produced by `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…`. Then use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to override aspects. This is mere speculation; I’ve not tried that.

Comment: Thanks. Android apparently offered a method in the `android.` namespace to get a format string for `SimpleDateFormatter`; when this becomes a big enough problem I'll see if I can translate it.